# Viewbox cuts off bottom of window using UniformToFill

Tags: c#, wpf, viewbox

So I'm developing a C# WPF Application. I want the MainWindow to always be maximized (which it is). The trouble came when I started thinking about resolutions. It has to adjust for the different screen resolutions. So, now I'm using a Viewbox (containing a grid). The Problem is I cannot use UniformToFill on the Stretch property for the ViewBox because it cuts off the bottom of the window. However, when I use "Uniform", it doesn't use the entire screen (which I really need). How do I get UniformToFill to Fill the window but not cut anything out? My Window code looks something like this:

```
<Window x:Name="AppMenu" x:Class="App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="App" FontWeight="Bold" Icon="Images/Core-IconSize.ico" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
          <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
             //Controls
          </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window
```

Comment: Don't use `Viewbox` as the primary layout container.  While some individuals think that it's a reasonable approach, it creates a similar situation to the one mobile devices had to deal with back in the day, when web pages would scale on them, rather than adjust their layout.

Comment: @B.K. Yes, got that. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeDinkler for the Viewbox you should always consider using the MaxHeight or MaxWidth properties, that way you'll never have your content cut. in your case, you should bind that to the window dimension, or do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should most probably re-think your layout. A `Viewbox` zooms your contained controls, which is not your usual behavior for almost any window. Usually, you want your controls to expand with the surrounding window. For example, a textbox would be longer in width, but the contained text would not be stretched horizontally (would look strange).

However, to answer your question: maybe you want `<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" .../>`, since it stretches the content to your full size, regardless of the aspect ratio.

See the following snippet for comparison of a few ways to stretch your content. Just paste it into your window and inspect the results. The first area (top left) just resizes the contained constrol, while the other three areas work with different stretch modes of the viewbox.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <TextBox Text="Test Area 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <TextBox Text="Test Area 2" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="1" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
            <TextBox Text="Test Area 3" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="1" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <TextBox Text="Test Area 4" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried `Fill` but it just makes my controls look pretty bad.

Comment: @LukeDinkler ofcourse it looks bad, but thats because it just has to look bad when you indiscriminately stretch the content to your window size. However, you explicitely state that you want it to stretch to the full size and you complain about cutoff in case of `UniformToFill`, so you don't have a lot of options left. However, as I stated, you may not want to use the viewbox at all, depending on what you actually want to archieve (ever heard of the [XY Problem?](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: Ok I see... But with your example above, you have to use a border control for _every_ control you add to your window?

Comment: @LukeDinkler No, I added the border so the extent of each area in the grid becomes visible. You can use the content of any border in the example without the surroundings. Think of it as a 4-window-presentation.

Comment: Hmm... well I'll give the example a try

Comment: I seem to have a rather stupid dilemma. Formatting the XAML for the grid in this way makes it so that I cannot arrange my controls on my window.

Comment: This is why I hate SO ^

Comment: Accepted this answer despite how mainly unhelpful it was because I was able to tweak your 'solution' to suit my needs.

Comment: @LukeDinkler I think the problem is, that you need a place to discuss your approach, while SO is a place to come with a specific problem and go with a more or less specific answer. You should consider joining a developer community forum, where you can discuss your ideas and focus on interactive improvements. You may learn things on SO, but it is not a learning platform by design.

Comment: You may be partially correct, however, this _was_ a specific problem and you were unwilling to help mitigate the _specific_ problems your solution caused.